# TeXlive on macOS Catalina,

Tags: texlive, mac

Does someone has upgraded to macOS Catalina without problem ?

PS: I have to work a lot with LaTeX at this time so I would be sure that the upgrading does not break TeXlive.

Comment: No problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, and biber all seem to work without any issues I've noticed. I don't use makeglossaries and so on, so I haven't got any handy test cases for them.

Fontspec etc. seem to work as expected, but I have not done complete tests.

Comment: Thanks. This looks very reassuring.

Comment: I have had no problem with makeglossaries or anything else as far as TeX Live (installed by MacTeX) is concerned.

Comment: I will do the upgrade. Thanks for your answers.